# Why are some solutions excluded if we simply multiply the denominator in an fraction inequality?

Tags: functions, inequality

I have the next inequality for which I have to find the solutions :

$$\frac{2x-5}{3x-1}\geq 1, \text{ where } x\in\mathbb{R}$$

I know I have to subtract $1$ and then I have to analyse the sign for the grade 1 function for both numerator and denominator and then see for which intervals they have different signs...

Why the approach of multiplying on both sides with $3x-1$ is incorrect?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because multiplying by  a negative quantity reverse the inequality, so you have to separe the two case: if the denominator is $>0$ or $<0$ ( and obviously exclude the case that it is $=0$).

Comment: Oh, right.. Thank you!

Answer (score 3):

$$a\ge b\iff\dfrac am\ge\dfrac bm$$ only if $m>0$

If $m<0,$  $$a\ge b\iff\dfrac am\le\dfrac bm$$

$$\dfrac{2x-5}{3x-1}\ge1\iff2x-5\ge3x-1$$  only if $3x-1>0$

Comment: @BogdanPop, $x=-2\iff3x-1<0$  For $3x-1<0$   $$\dfrac{2x-5}{3x-1}\ge1\iff2x-1\le-(3x-1)$$

Answer (score 0):

Because you neglect the sign of the polynomial: $3x-1$, it is a wrong solution. The actual way to solve is: 
\begin{align*}
\frac{2x-5}{3x-1} - 1 & \geq 0\\
\frac{2x-5 - 3x+1}{3x-1} & \geq 0\\
\frac{-x-4}{3x-1} & \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow (-x-4)(3x-1) \geq 0\\
(x + 4)(3x-1) & \geq 0
\end{align*}
$x \in (-\infty,-4] \cup \left[\frac{1}{3},+\infty\right)$.

Comment: Please read this [tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) on how to typeset mathematics on this site.  Your solution is incorrect.  $-x - 4 = -(x + 4)$.  Since multiplying or dividing an inequality by $-1$ reverses its direction, $$(-x - 4)(3x - 1) \geq 0 \Longleftrightarrow (x + 4)(3x - 1) \leq 0$$  The person who posted the question stated that he knew that he had to solve it by first subtracting $-1$, then analyzing the signs of the factors.  What he wanted to know is why he could not multiply the inequality by $3x - 1$.

Comment: Sorry for my misreading and bad-format incorrect answer. I'm not good at using the Mathml.